# Raid 1 across 3 partitions, what does it mean?

Tags: centos, raid, software-raid

I see a server with this kind of configuration. What does it mean?

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      48827264 blocks super 1.0 [3/3] [UUU]
```

Does it mean, mirroring the data across 3 drives, so there are 3 disks having the same data? 
What are the benefits? Is more read performance one of the benefits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux software RAID 1 implementation is a non-standard RAID level that can be composed of an odd number of disks, also called RAID 1E. Every strip is mirrored, normally over two of the disks, which allows you to recover from the failure of one disk. As with all RAID 1 it doubles the potential read performance compared to that of a single disk. With 3 disks you have an effective capacity of 2 disks. Extending the RAID1 with one disk to four turns it into RAID 1-0 volume.

```
2 drives (RAID1)   3 drives (RAID 1E)   4 drives (RAID 10)
--------           ----------          --------------
A1  A1             A1  A1  A2          A1  A1  A2  A2
A2  A2             A2  A3  A3          A3  A3  A4  A4
A3  A3             A4  A4  A5          A5  A5  A6  A6
A4  A4             A5  A6  A6          A7  A7  A8  A8
..  ..             ..  ..  ..          ..  ..  ..  ..
```

The reliability and capacity of this setup is the same as 3 disk RAID 5, but mirroring stripes is cheaper than calculating parity stripes.

In theory your set-up could also be a RAID1 where every stripe is mirrored thrice, but that seems unlikely, you could have triple the read performance, but only the cacpity of a single disk:

```
3 drives (RAID1)
--------------
A1  A1  A1
A2  A2  A2
A3  A3  A3 
A4  A4  A4
..  ..  ..
```

The command `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` will among others display the *Layout*. The  layout options for RAID10 are one of 'n', 'o' or 'f' followed by a small number. The number indicates the number of times a datablock is copied, the level of redundancy. The default is 'n2'. The supported options are:

> `n` signals 'near' copies. Multiple copies of one data block are at
>   similar offsets in different devices.
>
> `o` signals 'offset' copies. Rather than the chunks being duplicated
>   within a stripe, whole stripes are duplicated but are rotated by one
>   device so duplicate blocks are on different devices. Thus subsequent
>   copies of a block are in the next drive, and are one chunk further
>   down.
>
> `f` signals 'far' copies (multiple copies have very different
>   offsets). See md(4) for more detail about 'near', 'offset', and 'far

'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, this is the output. http://pb.abhijeetr.com/QPbh

Comment: That mdadm output appears to indicate that indeed every block is mirrored 3 times.

Comment: RAID1 mirrors over 3 drives are not that uncommon in my experience.

Comment: What you are describing is `raid10`, but the `mdstat` output in the question clearly says `raid1`. The `raid1` driver in Linux `md` can replicate to more than two disks. More than two replicas is useful for `/boot`, and it is useful if you want to be prepared to handle a few unreadable sectors during reconstruction after one disk has completely failed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical configuration for important data that needs to be accessed quickly, and database loads in general.

If you have a RAID1 with two disks, and one of them fails, you are left with no redundancy until the rebuild is complete, so any defective sector on the remaining disk will cause an error (which is also why RAID5 systems die so often).

Also, in database setups, random read performance is crucial. Having three disks gives you three sets of read/write heads that can be independently positioned, which improves performance greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a RAID using 3 disks, giving you additional read-speed and more fault-tolerance.

Comment: How is it more fault tolerant? You can still only lose 1 disk.

Comment: @ThatGraemeGuy: With RAID1 over three devices you can lose two devices without the array being toast. You might be thinking of linux's non-nested  RAID10 (what IBM RAID controllers call RAID1E) which has the same "can survive one drive lost" fault tolerance as RAID1 over two drives or RAID5 over 3.

Comment: I was referring to Linux's software RAID1 implementation, since that is what the question is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that setup on database servers, where admins wanted to do full backups, but didn't want to have extended downtimes on the databases. They created raid setups with 3 mirrors, and when it was time to backup, quiesced the database, removed one disk from the raid, did the backup from that disk, and after backup was finished, put the disk back into the raid and let the raid controller handle the re-mirroring.

This was almost 20 years ago; of course, these days, you'd rather use logical volumes and snapshots.